# Django Image Upload, No data in request.FILES['']

Tags: django, html, image

I have been simply trying to upload profile image, which I have done before. But this time the file is not uploading, even though the code is same. The image name is accessible from `request.data('image')`, but the image itself is not from `request.FILES['image']`

I have tried serializer, forms and direct way as well but still no progress.

Here is the code

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', null=True)

     def __str__(self):

        return self.user.name
```

**HTML code**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="file" name="myfile">
                                <button type="submit" name="upload-profile-photo">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**Views.py**

```
if 'upload-profile-photo' in request.POST:
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(user=token.user.id)
    profile_instance.image = request.FILES["myfile"]
    profile_instance.save()
    return HttpResponse("Success")
```

**Request Information**

```
GET: No Get Data
POST: csrfmiddlewaretoken: .....
      myfile: 'maxresdefault.jpg'
      upload-profile-photo: ''
FILES: No FILES data
```

Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 483, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 443, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/doel_registration_api/views.py", line 933, in post
    profile_instance.image = request.FILES["myfile"]
  File "/home/piyush/PycharmProjects/doel/doel/venv_doel/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 79, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'myfile'
```

Comment: try changing if condition to `if request.method == 'POST` in *views.py*

Comment: I tried, but got the same error again

Comment: You should first get the file with `image = request.FILES.get('myfile')` or if you wanted to allow multiple uploads `images = request.FILES.getlist('myfile')` to avoid these kind of exceptions (you're not using a Django Form, so you can never be sure that a file was actually submitted). That'll avoid the `KeyError`. Now that doesn't solve the first problem, why an image isn't submitted in the first place. Your HTML looks ok, except for the missing `action` attribute, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: changed to `image = request.FILES.get('myfile')`, Now `profile_instance.save()' saves empty('') to the database

Comment: What does your browser's nework tab say in the "developer tools" panel? Press F12 to activate the panel and repeat the upload. You should see the POST request listed, and you should be able to see whether the binary image data was included in the request.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same problem, then I found the error.
the error is not in views files or models files, the error is in HTML code.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

inside `<form>` tag make sure to add it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I found out that the problem was with my **HTML code**. Here are some suggestions, see if it works-

Check your `<form>` code.
 Try adding `<input type="submit">` instead of `<button>`

See if adding `action` attribute to form tag  would help.